# What is the difference between <tf.io.parse_single_example> and <tf.data.experimental.parse_example_dataset>?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am beginner in tensorflow and studying how to use tfrecord dataset.

is there any difference between <tf.io.parse_single_example> and <tf.data.experimental.parse_example_dataset> ??

version of tensorflow is 2.3.0

## for Mnist example

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

def feature_float_list(l):
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=l))

def record2example(r_x, r_y):
    return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        "x": feature_float_list(r_x),
        "y": feature_float_list(r_y)
    }))

filename_test  = "test.tfrecords"

# Data of MNIST to tfrecord file
_, (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
print("x_test: ", x_test.shape)  # x_test    :  (10000, 28, 28)
print("y_test: ", y_test.shape)  # y_test    :  (10000,)
x_test  = x_test.reshape((-1, 28*28)).astype("float32") / 255.0
y_test  = y_test.reshape((-1, 1)).astype("float32")

with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(filename_test) as writer:
    for r_x, r_y in zip(x_test, y_test):
        ex = record2example(r_x, r_y)
        writer.write(ex.SerializeToString())

#output
#x_test:(10000, 28, 28)
#y_test:(10000,)
```

## and,load tfrecord dataset  like below

```
feature_dim=784 

def parse_example(example):
    features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, features={
        "x": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([feature_dim], dtype=tf.float32),
        "y": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.float32)
    })
    x = features["x"]
    y = features["y"]
    return x, y

#-----tf.io.parse_single_example -----ver-----

def create_dataset_1():
    
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(["test.tfrecords"]).map(parse_example)

    dataset = dataset.repeat()

    buffer_size=10
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size)
    
    #batchsize
    batch_size=10
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    
    # set iterator
    iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset)
    image, label = iterator.get_next()

    return image, label

image,label=create_dataset_1()
print(image.shape)
print(label.shape)

#(10, 784)
#(10,)
```

```
#-----tf.data.experimental.parse_example_dataset -----ver-----

def dict2tuple(feature):
    return feature["x"], feature["y"]

def create_dataset_2():

    feature_dim=784
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(["test.tfrecords"]).batch(100).apply(tf.data.experimental.parse_example_dataset(
        {
              "x": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([feature_dim], dtype=tf.float32),
              "y": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.float32)
          })).map(dict2tuple)
        
    #set repeat and shuffle
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(10)
    
    # batchsize
    #batch_size=10
    #dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    
    #iterator
    iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset)
    
    image, label = iterator.get_next()

    return image, label

image,label=create_dataset_2()
print(image.shape)
print(label.shape)

#(100, 784)
#(100,)
```

I tried to look it up but,could not find this,think both outputs is the same....,
which should I use <tf.io.parse_single_example> and <tf.data.experimental.parse_example_dataset> ?

Answer (score 1):

There is not much difference in both cases.

In `tf.data.experimental.parse_example_dataset` the below apply function is retuned.

```
def _apply_fn(dataset):
    """Function from Dataset to Dataset that applies the transformation."""
    out_dataset = _ParseExampleDataset(dataset, features, num_parallel_calls,
                                       deterministic)
    if any(
        isinstance(feature, parsing_ops.SparseFeature) or
        (isinstance(feature, parsing_ops.RaggedFeature) and feature.partitions)
        for feature in features.values()):
      # pylint: disable=protected-access
      # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
      out_dataset = out_dataset.map(
          lambda x: parsing_ops._construct_tensors_for_composite_features(
              features, x),
          num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls)
    return out_dataset

  return _apply_fn
```

Where in `tf.io.parse_single_example`   Parses a serialized Example protos given in serialized which is similar to `tf.io.parse_example`, except `tf.io.parse_example` is serialized in batches.

You can use `tf.io.parse_example` for performance advantage over batching samples.

Comment: I’m sorry for the very late.  its unique to make iterator and dataset in tensorflow  compared with pytorch,,,,,this is helpful for me. Thank you for your advice/